# Passing array elements to foreach divs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass string elements from an array `myArr` while selecting the div it should go into with a forEach loop, so that each of the four div elements below has a corresponding string element from the array.

I'm having some trouble with it, because I'm selecting the divs with a `querySelectorAll` method. Help would be appreciated. This code below is just a sample of what I'm working on, so it can't be altered too much.

HTML

```
<div class="number">old number</div>
<div class="number">old number</div>
<div class="number">old number</div>
<div class="number">old number</div>
```

JS

```
var numberDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
var myArr = ['number1','number2', 'number3', 'number4'];

    numberDivs.forEach(function(el) {   
        el.innerHTML = "new number";

      for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; ++i) {
          el.innerHTML = myArr[i];
    }    
});
```

Right now, it's (`el`) only passing through the last element in the array to **all** divs, instead of the corresponding one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var numberDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
var myArr = ['number1','number2', 'number3', 'number4'];
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
      numberDivs[i].innerHTML = myArr[i];  
}
```

You're issue was you had a for loop going across all the elements, then another for loop  going across your array. The inner for loop, the one for you're array, would always end at the last element, therefore each object - the divs - ended at the final element of that array.

http://jsfiddle.net/a8zrkejo/

Answer (score 2):

I think is this what you want:

```
numberDivs.forEach(function(el, i) {
    el.innerHTML = myArr[i];
});
```

This assumes they are of equal length, and won't overwrite each element's HTML like your code is currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix, if you're certain the total count of the array is same as the number of divs 
then loop the array only and use the index of each element to access the div.

```
var numberDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
var myArr = ['number1','number2', 'number3', 'number4'];
myArr.forEach(function(value, Index) {
    numberDivs[Index].innerHTML = value
});
```